# Multiply tables need to save to many record in another table

Tags: sql-server, relationship

I have 7 existing tables that are tech related hardware. i.e. PC, server, ip phones, and so forth.

Now they want to store the MAC Address for each device in a MAC address Table. Normally this would not be a problem for me but here's were I get lost.

Out of the 7 different hardware tables some have multiply MAC Address while the rest have only one.

The only way I can think to make this work is to Create the MAC address table like below.

```
--List of the 7 tables
Create Table TableName (  
     TableNameID        Bigint Primary Key Identity Not Null,
     TableName          Varchar(30) Not Null,
)

--The table that hold the MAC address
Create Table MacAddress (
     MacAddressID        Int Primary Key Identity Not Null,
     MacAddress          Char(25) Unique Not Null,
     TableNameID         Int Not Null,
     HardwareTableID     Int Not Null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Telephone_MacAddress  FOREIGN KEY (HarewareTableID) REFERENCES Telephone(TelephoneID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Printer_MacAddress FOREIGN KEY (HarewareTableID) REFERENCES Printer(PrinterID),

)
```

I was thinking of creating the above and making the HardwareTableID a foreign key to all the other tables, and then using the TableName as a way to identify the Table for which it is linked to. I also thought about using a third table that would normal be used for a many to many relationship but I'd still need some way to know which table the record is linked to.

If anyone has a better way doing this i'd love to hear it.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 for the database.

Hopefully I explained this well enough. Please let me know if you need clarification as I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can add the foreign keys as you wanted. If there are multiple tables storing different devices, foreign key on the device ids are not practical. The tableNameId actually is an enforceable foreign key. Also, do you really need BigInt for the tablenameID?

Comment: Ouch!!! I would have created an extra column in your hardware table to identify the type instead of a different table for each type. If at all possible I would go back and change that. Otherwise you have to keep creating new tables everytime you get a new type of hardware.